# Using MpAndroidChart-CombinedChart, how to separate the chart into an upper and lower portion?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

In the following image I've plotted a day's worth of prices and the trading volume per hour.
To achieve this I'm using a `CombinedChart` type. You can immediately see that the volume data distracts the user from the price data because both charts fill the screen.

**QUESTION:**
Is there a way to reserve 25% of the bottom of the chart for volume and 75% of the top of the chart for prices ?

[image: bitcoin prices and volume]

**Code is as follows:**

```
private void setupChart(){
    chart.setAutoScaleMinMaxEnabled(true);
    chart.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    chart.setPinchZoom(false);
    chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    chart.getLegend().setEnabled(true);
    chart.setDrawOrder(new CombinedChart.DrawOrder[]{ CombinedChart.DrawOrder.BAR, CombinedChart.DrawOrder.CANDLE });// draw bars behind candles

    // right side is for the volume
    YAxis rightAxis = chart.getAxisRight();
    rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    rightAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    chart.resetTracking();

    ArrayList<HistoricPrice> historicPrices = presenter.getHistoricalDataGranular(DEFAULT_GRANULARITY_MINS);

    ArrayList<CandleEntry> valuesCandles = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<BarEntry> valuesBars = new ArrayList<>();


    for (int i = progress; (i < progress+MAX_CANDLES_COUNT) && (i < historicPrices.size()); i++) {
        HistoricPrice historicPrice = historicPrices.get(i);
        CandleEntry candleEntry = new CandleEntry(i, historicPrice.high.floatValue(), historicPrice.low.floatValue(), historicPrice.open.floatValue(), historicPrice.close.floatValue());
        valuesCandles.add(candleEntry);
        BarEntry barEntry = new BarEntry(i, Float.valueOf(historicPrice.volume.toPlainString()));
        valuesBars.add(barEntry);
    }

    CandleDataSet set1 = new CandleDataSet(valuesCandles, "Prices");
    set1.setDrawIcons(false);
    set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    set1.setShadowColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    set1.setShadowWidth(0.7f);
    set1.setDecreasingColor(Color.RED);
    set1.setDecreasingPaintStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    set1.setIncreasingColor(Color.rgb(122, 242, 84));
    set1.setIncreasingPaintStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    set1.setNeutralColor(Color.BLUE);
    set1.setDrawValues(true);
    set1.setShowCandleBar(true);
    CandleData candleData = new CandleData(set1);

    BarDataSet set2 = new BarDataSet(valuesBars, "Volume");
    set2.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.blue_grey));
    set2.setDrawValues(true);
    set2.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
    BarData barData = new BarData(set2);

    CombinedData data = new CombinedData();
    data.setData(candleData);
    data.setData(barData);


    chart.setData(data);
    chart.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can set the wether the data set is dependant on leftAxis or rightAxis. So you set set1 dependant on leftAxis and set2 on RightAxis. After doing thing this call set1.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum(minValue) from where the graph will start.
have a look at the below snippet

```
CandleDataSet set1 = new CandleDataSet(valuesCandles, "Prices");
set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
set1.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum(minValue)

BarDataSet set2 = new BarDataSet(valuesBars, "Volume");
set2.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
```

Comment: I don't think that'll work - if I set the right axis to a minimum of 800, I would lose a lot of info from the graph and the large peak of 2241 would still stick out into the financial data of the graph